# Upgraded go_router, now routeInformation's state is always null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router, gorouter

On loading my flutter app, I get the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:go_router/src/parser.dart': Failed assertion: line 64 pos 12: 'routeInformation.state != null': is not true.)
```

This has started happening after an upgrade from **3.1.0** to **10.1.0** of `go_router`

Some of the changes I made to even get this building (after the upgrade):

[image]

I read from the changelog (https://pub.dev/packages/go_router/changelog) that urlPathStrategy had been altogether removed (so I removed it) and that the params props had changes.

The stacktrace is not particularly helpful here, but in case it is:

[image]

Would really appreciate any help in resolving this! I've spent hours on it. I appreciate it's quite a jump in the version but I've had to bring it up to date.

Note, this is the other piece of code I think may be relevant:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'my app',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        FFLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: _locale,
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', '')],
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      themeMode: _themeMode,
      routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I don't think this is relevant since it seems a runtime error rather than a compilation error, but here's my flutter doc output anyway:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.13.2 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ff5b5b5fa6 (3 weeks ago), 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
    • Engine revision b20183e040
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33205.214
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] VS Code (version 1.80.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2134]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.188
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.203

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: You should read the changelog for breaking changes.  Going from 3.x to 10.x is QUITE a change.  Your interface to MaterialApp got significantly simpler, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RandalSchwartz! Ye quite a change indeed. So this is exported code from 'flutterflow' and their code exported 3.x not too long ago. So I'm finding quite a few libs need upgrading and it's causing mayhem!

Comment: Perhaps another reason not to use Flutterflow?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz - one of many. Flutterflow gave me the headstart Ineeded and provided a lot of scaffolding, but if I knew I'd be chasing my tail with dependencies I'd have been a little more careful. Shoulda woulda coulda.

Comment: It's like training wheels on a motorcycle.  Fine to get started, but watch out when you gotta lean into that first turn...